# recursive grep but skip symlinks to another filesystem

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I know I can do recursive grep by doing `grep -r ./`

What if I want to skip all symlinks to a different file-system and only stay within the current one? The other file system has way too much data I am not interested in.

But if it's a symlink to the same filesystem, I would like to still grep it.

Similar to -x option when you use `du` to calculate the free space.

Comment: `find -xdev -exec grep 'pattern' {} +` ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with grep alone. `-r` follows links encountered on the command line, but none encountered recursively; `-R` follows *all* symlinks. Glutton's `find` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Make sure to use the "-H" option to grep to print the filename using @Gluttton's great answer.